# Unable to locate cookie acceptance window within iframe using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to use `https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot` within iframe using Selenium in Python, but seem unable to locate the acceptance button for the cookie popup window.

Here's the code I built:

```
url = 'https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot'
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button")
for ind, b in enumerate(button):
    print(ind, b.text.strip())
button[53].click()
```

Image:
[image]

But I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

When I inspect the elements in the driver, it seems it contains the page in the background, but not the cookie popup window. I also tried, if it would be an `alert`, but it didn't seem to be.

Any ideas how to go forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>OK</kbd> for cookie acceptance is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://cdn.privacy-mgmt.com/index']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='OK']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://cdn.privacy-mgmt.com/index')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='OK']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works!