# How do you accept cookies across multiple websites?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of domains that I would like to loop over and screenshot using selenium. However, the cookie consent column means the full page is not viewable. Most of them have different consent buttons - what is the best way of accepting these? Or is there another method that could achieve the same results?

urls for reference: docjournals.com, elcomercio.com, maxim.com, wattpad.com, history10.com

[image]

Comment: Plese  provide the url as text instead of an image.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to click accept individually for every website.
You can do that, using

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your_XPATH_locator").click()
```

Comment: Won't the XPATH locator vary by website since they have different acceptance text?

Comment: Yes, it most certainly will.

Answer (score 0):

From the snapshot

[image: snapshot]

as you can observe diffeent urls have different consent buttons, they may vary with respect to:

- *innerText*
- *tag*
- *attributes*
- *implementation* ([**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) / [**shadowRoot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447))

---

### Conclusion

There can't be a generic solution to accept/deny the cookie concent as at times:

- You may need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and click on the concent.
- You may need to switch to an iframe. See: [Unable to locate cookie acceptance window within iframe using Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65922588/7429447)
- You may need to traverse within a shadowRoot. See: [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735009/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

To get around the XPATH selectors varying from page to page you can use
`driver.current_url` and use the url to figure out which selector you need to use. 
Or alternatively if you iterate over them anyways you can do it like this:

```py
page_1 = {
    'url' : 'docjournals.com'
    'selector' : 'example_selector_1'
}

page_2 = {
    'url' = 'elcomercio.com'
    'selector' : 'example_selector_2'
}

pages = [page_1, page_2]
for page in pages:
    driver.get(page.url)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, page.selector).click()
```